# Python application exiting when importing user defined module(pandas, numpy etc.)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I installed python 3.8.5(32-bit) and
I added python paths properly

- D:\SW\Python38; D:\SW\Python38\Scripts; D:\SW\Python38\Lib;
  D:\SW\Python38\Lib\site-packages

I tried to import user-defined module in command line window as well as IDLE.

[image]

[image]

In the program print function is not working as **python is closing** without error or exception.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have not tried installing the Packages(There is almost no information to clarify whether this statement is true or not)

use this command:
**pip install numpy**

usage: pip install (PackageName)

Comment: I installed pandas, numpy etc with pip install command only
If it is not installed, i should get ModuleNotFoundError exception here, but I did not get any exception or error.

Comment: Have you tried using an IDE ? It might be that you did not install Python properly, try using some IDE (Like Pycharm or VSC, I highly recommend Pycharm), and also IDE usually does all the Python Set-up Automatically  . But the issue with this post is that there is extremely little amount of information to use to resolve your problem.